# Insert div.row at 1, 4, 7... in Javascript (node.js)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to create the following HTML structure with some dynamic data using a for loop.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="column">
   <div class="column">
   <div class="column">
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="column">
   <div class="column">
   <div class="column">
</div>
```

Below is what I've tried

```
<% for (var key in video) { %>

    <% if (key%3 == 0 ) { %>
        <div class="row">
    <% } %>

      <div class="column video <%=parseInt(key)+1%>">
       ...
      </div>

    <% if (key%3 == 0 ) { %> 
        </div>
    <% } %>  

  <% } %>
```

But with this I'm getting

```
<div class="row>
   <div class="column">
</div>
<div class="column">
<div class="column">
<div class="row>
   <div class="column">
</div>
<div class="column">
<div class="column">
```

What can I do to wrap  in a desirable way?

Comment: why aren't you using a table?

Comment: Because I'm using a responsive grid framework to make it responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the condition `<% if (key%3 == 0 ) { %>` is met twice in the same loop.

Place a starting row and closing row outside the loop then on the condition do an all in one close and open of a new div.

```
<div class="row">
<% for (var key in video) { %>

    <% if (key%3 == 0 && key != 0) { %>
        </div><div class="row">
    <% } %>

      <div class="column video <%=parseInt(key)+1%>">
       ...
      </div>

  <% } %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. it works great. I didn't think of this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering of the open and close tags for `<div class="row"></div>` needs to be interchanged.

Conditionals are put in to make sure that when `key = 0`, the closing tag won't be inserted, and when it's reaching the last `key`, the last row will only have a closing tag.

```
<% for (var key in video) { %>

    <% if (key%3 == 0 && key!=0) { %> 
        </div>
    <% } %>  

      <div class="column video <%=parseInt(key)+1%>">
       ...
      </div>

    <% if (key%3 == 0) { %>
        <div class="row">
    <% } %>

<% } %>
```

Comment: I only chose the other answer because it was simpler. Thank you, yours worked great as well.